# Chrome - annoying window.onpopstate loading cursor

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, single-page-application, html5-history

I'm running a single-page application which loads all `<a>` links via AJAX. This is a minor visual annoyance, but ever since I switched from #hash tag navigation to proper history via `window.onpopstate` and `window.history.pushState()`, many clicks in the system will cause the cursor to "load" as if it were a standard non-AJAX page. On Windows, I get the pointer with the loading symbol. This is in contrast to before where it would simply load the AJAX into the container and never change the cursor. I feel this "breaks the immersion" of being a single-page application.

My code is simple:

```
$('body').on("click", 'a', function() {
var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({type:'GET', url: url, success: function(data) {
        window.history.pushState({}, url, url);
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});

    return false;
}
});

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  run_url();
};
```

This works as intended in Firefox. If I remove window.onpopstate completely, it no longer does this, but I cannot find an alternative to onpopstate.